# Console.ReadKey(true) needs two key presses to display one input

Tags: c#, .net-core, console-application

I'm using two threads. One for displaying some info. The other for the input handling. Currently, I have to enter a keystroke twice before it adds it to the input.

I already tried to lock input when a keypress has been done, but that didn't fix it.

```cs
class min
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        min p = new min();
    }

    public min()
    {
        DetailsMenu(1);
    }

    List<string> active = new List<string>() { "Example1", "Example2", "Example3" };

    string input = "";
    int index;

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a detail menu
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="index">What name</param>
    public void DetailsMenu(int index)
    {
        Console.CursorVisible = false;
        this.index = index;
        Thread Input = new Thread(new ThreadStart(DetailMenuInput));
        Thread Details = new Thread(new ThreadStart(DetailsMenuThread));
        Input.Start();
        Details.Start();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Displays the screen it self
    /// </summary>
    void DetailsMenuThread()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine($"{active[index - 1]}");
            Console.SetCursorPosition(0, Console.WindowHeight - 1);
            Console.WriteLine($">{input}_");
            Console.SetWindowPosition(0, 0);
            Thread.Sleep(100);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Needs to handle input
    /// in this function i need to press a key twice to add it to input
    /// </summary>
    void DetailMenuInput()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            Console.TreatControlCAsInput = false;
            var key = Console.ReadKey(true);
            if (key.Key == ConsoleKey.Backspace)
            {
                if (input.Length > 0)
                    input = input.Remove(input.Length - 1);
                continue;
            }
            input += Console.ReadKey(true).KeyChar.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

What I would like: for only one key stroke to be needed for one character to be input.

What happens instead: I need to press the key twice to add it to the input string.

No error messages are displayed when I run this code.

Comment: what is `active`?

Comment: Acitve is just a list of strings

Comment: you call ReadKey twice? and you are wondering why you need to press a key twice?   It's worth using a debugger and tracing what happens with your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What I would like: for only one key stroke to be needed for one character to be input.
>
> What happens instead: I need to press the key twice to add it to the input string.

You need to press the key twice, because your loop reads the key twice before accepting input. Indeed, the only key actually treated as real input is the second key press. The first can be anything other than the backspace key.

Instead of reading the key twice, just use the `key` variable that contains the original key that was read:

```
void DetailMenuInput()
{
    while (true)
    {
        Console.TreatControlCAsInput = false;
        var key = Console.ReadKey(true);
        if (key.Key == ConsoleKey.Backspace)
        {
            if (input.Length > 0)
                input = input.Remove(input.Length - 1);
            continue;
        }
        input += key.KeyChar.ToString();
    }
}
```